# Class namespace inside a typedef inside the same class?

Tags: c++, typedef

I've run across some code that looks like

myClass.h:

```
class MyClass
{
...
private:
    typedef     int (MyClass::*myFunc_t)(void);
}
```

Does including the `MyClass::` inside the typedef do anything here or is it redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does do something: it specifies that the type is a pointer to a member function. Without it, it would be a pointer to a non-member (or static member) function.

To illustrate the difference:

```
struct MyClass
{
    int mem_fun(); // member function
};

int non_mem_fun(); // non-member function

typedef int (MyClass::*mem_fun_ptr)();  // pointer to member
typedef int (*non_mem_fun_ptr)();       // pointer to non-member

MyClass object;

mem_fun_ptr mfp = &MyClass::mem_fun;    // points to a member function
(object.*mfp)();                        // needs an object to call the function

non_mem_fun_ptr mnfp = non_mem_fun;     // points to a non-member function
nmfp();                                 // called without an object
```

Comment: thank you, this part of the explanation was particularly enlightening: `// needs an object to call the function`